# How to loop through an array of parameters and relate them to each other

Tags: c#

I'm trying to loop through an array of params and associating them with on another in the order they are looped through (The class is of type **Payment** with a property **SupplementalPayment** also of type Payment).
So it would be that with 4 payments, payment 4 would be associated to payment 3 and payment 3 would be associated to payment 2 and so on.

I'm having trouble making it that it will do this with an unlimited amount of parameters.

This is where I am right now with the method:

```
private Payment SortPayments(params Payment[] payments)
    {
        Payment parentPayment, lastPayment;

        lastPayment = parentPayment = null;

        foreach (Payment currentPayment in payments)
        {
            if (currentPayment != null)
            {
                lastPayment = currentPayment;

                if (parentPayment == null)
                {
                    parentPayment = lastPayment;
                }
                else if(parentPayment.SupplementalPayment == null)
                {
                    parentPayment.SupplementalPayment = lastPayment;
                }
                else if (parentPayment.SupplementalPayment.SupplementalPayment == null)
                {
                    parentPayment.SupplementalPayment = lastPayment;
                }
                else if (parentPayment.SupplementalPayment.SupplementalPayment.SupplementalPayment == null)
                {
                    parentPayment.SupplementalPayment.SupplementalPayment.SupplementalPayment = lastPayment;
                }
            }
        }

        return parentPayment;
    }
```

As you can see it is not dynamic and will only do up to four supplementalpayments. Anyone have any idea how to go about this?

Comment: You could be using a while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this, using a loop:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Payments
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Payment p1 = new Payment();
            Payment p2 = new Payment();
            Payment p3 = new Payment();

            Payment Sorted = SortPayments(p1, p2, p3);
        }

        static private Payment SortPayments(params Payment[] payments)
        {
            if(payments.Length == 0)
            {
               return null;
            }

            Payment FirstPayment = payments[0];

            Payment current = FirstPayment;
            for (int i = 1; i < payments.Length; i++ )
            {
                current.SupplementalPayment = payments[i];
                current = current.SupplementalPayment;
            }

            return FirstPayment;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried using using a while loop but just didn't get to the point of figuring it out. Anyway the code you posted would never start the while loop as parentpayment was never given a supplemental payment yet.

Comment: @RichardMc - I haven't tested it, it is just a scratch to give you a hint how to start.

Comment: Selected this as the correct answer as it has the most effort in it. BlackBear's answer also answered my question sufficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am not understanding your question at all, but you are just trying to link each payment to the next one. In this case a simple for loop is enough:

```
private Payment SortPayments(params Payment[] payments)
{
    if(payments.Length == 0) return null;

    for(int i = 0; i < payments.Length - 1; i++)
        payments[i].SupplementalPayment = payments[i + 1]

    return payments[0];
}
```

Comment: I got it the same way. Richard, this is what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an Array of payments, perhaps you could use a `LinkedList<Payments>` instead.

This way you could loop through the collection and assign the Previous node to the supplementary Payment property.

[LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[LinkedListNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are unlimited ways how to do it.
What first comes to my mind (probably not remotely optimal) is recursion and stack of active parameters. 
Just organize your data into a list of lists. A recursive function "visit" loops over one list, pushes the element on the stack and calls visit for the next list until there is no list to visit. In the end you have the stack of related elements.

After your recurrence call you pop from the stack.
This needs polishing, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback guys. This is what I have ended up with.
Only difference is from the answers is it accounts for some of the params entered to be null.

```
    private Payment SortPayments(params Payment[] payments)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < payments.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (payments[i + 1] != null)
            {
                payments[i].SupplementalPayment = payments[i + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                int j = 1;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (payments[i + j] == null)
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        payments[i].SupplementalPayment = payments[i + j];
                        i += j;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return payments[0];
    }
```